# Use of the term "consecutive" to describe a single item

Tags: grammatical-number, terminology, programming

There's an exercise on [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/domains), a programming website, that asks me to find the number of consecutive 1s in a binary representation of a decimal number (e.g. 5 is 101 in binary). The author of the problem gave sample inputs and outputs along with his explanations:

> Sample Case 1: 
>   The binary representation of 5 is 101, so the maximum number of consecutive 1's is 1.
>
> Sample Case 2: 
>   The binary representation of 13 is 1101, so the maximum number of consecutive 1's is 2.

Why are there 1 consecutive 1s in the number 101? The term **consecutive** by its very definition implies sequential multiplicity. It makes sense to say that there are two consecutive 1s in the second example because there is a single "1" followed by yet another "1", but why does it make sense to say there are 1 consecutive 1s? I've never heard anyone use the term "consecutive" to describe a single item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First note the context in which these examples are presented - namely in the context of programming.

It is true that colloquially we would not say that there is one consecutive instance of the digit 1.  However, in the more formal setting of programming it is desirable to handle exceptions without dealing with special cases.  This is because case handling is generally considered to be inelegant in programming.

Therefore, a programmer will most likely write a *method* (called, for example countConsecutive(String, String)) that simply counts the number of "consecutive" instances of some string in another string and then call this the number of consecutive instances.

For example, the programmer's method would most likely say that there are zero consecutive twos in the string "101".

Comment: +1. To be more formal, the author of the problem should have ask for the length of the longest sequence of 1s.

Comment: @Graffito Yes, this would certainly make these examples more transparent. Unfortunately, in my experience, a programmer's ability to express themself formally ends at their coding ;-)

Comment: @Graffito Ahhh, that phrasing is so much better! I guess that's what they meant to say. Thank you both.

Comment: This sort of language is also common in mathematics.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes indeed.  To the uninitiated, saying something like "this is trivially true for the empty set" would be rather perplexing.

Comment: @NWR "a programmer's ability to express themself formally ends at their coding" I call foul here.  In fact, this almost sounds contradictory in itself; if the programming community consistently uses the term consecutive to allow single instances, that is only evidence _that_ the term formally includes single instances at least within this community.  To suggest that rather this is evidence that programmers generally cannot express themselves is not only a distraction; it's a hindrance.

Comment: @HWalters No problems with your formal reasoning!  It was just a tongue in cheek, snarky comment.  I wouldn't take it too seriously.

Comment: @Graffito "should have ask for the length of the longest sequence of 1s." No, he shouldn't have, because `1101` simply isn't a sequence of 1's, and there's nowhere to go from here.  _Formally_ the author would ask for the length of the longest substring containing only 1's, but this requires an audience knowing what the formal definition of a substring is.  I think _consecutive_ is a really good way to convey what the author meant, especially when given a border case example to clarify; indeed, _even the OP_ knew what was meant by the challenge.

Answer (score 4):

Think of 'consecutive' here as 'in a row'.  In 1101 you have three ones, but only two in a row.